# Where are webapps in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, webapps

I just read this blogpost: http://www.howtogeek.com/119560/how-to-install-and-use-ubuntus-new-web-apps-feature/

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and I tried to install as stated in the link, but `sudo apt-get update` says:

"Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webapps/preview/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found"

I read elsewhere that webapps should come preinstalled, but I can find no trace of them. When I open gmail in Firefox, it doesn't prompt about web integration.

Have they gotten rid of web apps in 15.10, or is something wrong in my case?

Comment: The article has been written way back in 2012. As of now, you could simply  run `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-SOMEWEBAPP` . Just search through the list using ` apt-cache search unity-webapps` and pick what you want. So technically you can remove that ppa and forget about all this trouble

Comment: Mind if I convert that into an actual answer ?

Comment: No, I accepted it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article has been written way back in 2012. As of now, you could simply run `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-SOMEWEBAPP` . Just search through the list using `apt-cache search unity-webapps` and pick what you want. So technically you can remove that ppa and forget about all this trouble

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the PPA project is still up and active. So the error you have encountered might be caused of the "Server Selection". Make sure to set the Download from Server to "Main Server" as some mirror servers are not up-to-date.

Go to System Settings > Software and Updates > Ubuntu Software > Change the Download from to "Main Server" > Make sure it updates the cache

Then try re-installing WEBAPPS.

Comment: It's not that, it seems like it is just not available for the 15.10 distro: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webapps/preview/ubuntu/dists/

But I read somewhere that webapps come preinstalled in newer Ubuntu versions, but it doesn't look that way.

Comment: Issue is that, there is no package yet for wily. Here are the list of packages it supports. http://ppa.launchpad.net/webapps/preview/ubuntu/dists/